# Clone ownership and permissions from another file?

Tags: shell, permissions, files, chown

Is there a command or flag to clone the user/group ownership and permissions on a file from another file? To make the perms and ownership exactly those of another file?

Comment: Related questions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/56792/how-to-copy-only-file-attributes-metadata-without-actual-content-of-the-file/143092 and
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44253/how-to-clone-copy-all-file-directory-attributes-onto-different-file-directory

Answer (score 223, accepted):

On GNU/Linux `chown` and `chmod` have a `--reference` option

```
chown --reference=otherfile thisfile
chmod --reference=otherfile thisfile
```

Comment: Could you reference to this answer (and likely cite it) as answer to my question : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44253/how-to-clone-copy-all-directory-attributes-permission-ownership-times-exte ? , I think I will be great addition and I'd love to find up-votes there for it.

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki: probably that question should be closed, but is a little bit different than this and already has answers, so I better do nothing.

Comment: As you wish and suggest. Thanks for help, I have never put attention to `--reference` parameter of `chmod` and `chown` before :).

Answer (score 13):

On any unix with GNU utilities, such as (non-embedded) Linux or Cygwin, you can use [`chmod --reference` and `chown --reference`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20645/clone-ownership-and-permissions-from-another-file/20646#20646).

If your system has [ACLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_Control_List), try the ACL commands `getfacl` and `setfacl`. These commands differ a little from system to system, but on many you can use `getfacl other_file | setfacl -bnM - file_to_change` to copy the permissions. This doesn't copy the ownership; you can do that with careful parsing of `ls -l other_file`, assuming that you don't have user or group names containing whitespace.

```
LC_ALL=C ls -l other_file | {
  read -r permissions links user group stuff;
  chown -- "$user:$group" file_to_change
}
getfacl other_file | setfacl -bnM - file_to_change
```

Comment: You should have ACL installed and filesystem mounted with ACL enabled.

Comment: @enzotib At least on Linux, ACL tools will work to copy permissions (but not ownership) even if the source and target filesystem don't support ACLs.

Comment: Pour info, on RHEL 7 (and possibly onwards) you can use `getfacl other_file | setfacl --set-file=- file_to_change`.

Answer (score 10):

Did a [bash command](https://gist.github.com/mjlescano/5e0b5f91b1d368ca6bd0) based on the response of [Matteo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/10616/matteo) :)

**Code:**

`chmod $( stat -f '%p' "$1" ) "${@:2}"`

**Usage:**

`cp-permissions <from> <to>...`

Comment: Egad!  Where did you learn to say `${*:2}`?  Don't ever do that again!  That will fail if any of the filenames contain space (or tabs).  Use `"${@:2}"`.  Also, use `"$1"` instead of just `$1`.

Comment: `chmod "$(stat -c '%a' "$fromfile")" tofile` in GNU Coreutils, but you might as well use `--reference` in that case since the`stat` CLI utility is not POSIX, it even says http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.htmlthat `ls -l` won't cut it: "The output of ls (with the -l and related options) contains information that logically could be used by utilities such as chmod and touch to restore files to a known state. However, this information is presented in a format that cannot be used directly by those utilities or be easily translated into a format that can be used."

Answer (score 4):

If you are not using a system with GNU's chmod/chown (which support the `--reference` option) you could try to parse the output of `ls -l`

Here a small script for `chmod` (if you have a see which supports extended regexes they could be written in a much more readable way ...)

```
#!/bin/sh

reference=$1
shift
files=$*

# strip the permissions (whith extended regexes could be more readable)
OWNER=$(ls -l ${reference} | sed -e "s/.\(...\).*/\1/"       | sed -e "s/[-]//g" )
GROUP=$(ls -l ${reference} | sed -e "s/....\(...\).*/\1/"    | sed -e "s/[-]//g" )
OTHER=$(ls -l ${reference} | sed -e "s/.......\(...\).*/\1/" | sed -e "s/[-]//g" )

chmod u=${OWNER},g=${GROUP},o=${OTHER} ${files}
```

**UPDATE**:

This is even easier using `stat`:

```
chmod $( stat -f '%p' ${reference} ) ${files}
```

Comment: Instead of parsing `ls -l` output, you could you could parse `stat`output.

Comment: @jfgagne: thanks makes sense I do not know why I didn't think about it in the first place. I updated the answer

Comment: You're using *BSD `stat` syntax here. Your `chmod $(stat ...)` command won't work because `%p` alone outputs too much information for *BSD's `chmod`, use `%Lp` to output just the u/g/o bits. Something slightly more elaborate would be required for sticky/setuid/setgid bits.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

`cp -p --attributes-only <from> <to>`

Comment: That copies *all* attributes though (change `-p` to `--preserve=ownership,mode` to copy only permissions and ownership (and ACLs if any)). That will also not work for files of type *directory*. Also note that if `<to>` is a symlink, that will copy the attributes to the target of the symlink (likely what one would want anyway as permissions of symlinks themselves are rarely relevant (though ownership can be)).

Answer (score 2):

On MacOS, `cp --attributes-only` or `chmod --reference` won't work.

A solution for MacOS is to first install `coreutils` using

```bsh
brew install coreutils
```

then use the `coreutils`'s version of `cp` command, that is `gcp`:

```bsh
gcp --attributes-only --archive  sourcefile destfile
```

This will copy the ownership and attributes while preserving `destfile`'s content and filename.

Comment: note that `--archive` works recursively, which is not necessarily what one may want.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add an adjustment to [Matteo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/10616/matteo)'s script. A for loop should be used to validate that the files exist before actually running the chmod command on them. This will let the script error out more gracefully.

I think this is the best option because it can be used for all *nix OSes, like Solaris, Linux, etc.

```
#!/bin/sh

reference=$1
shift
files=$*

for file in $reference $files; do
  [ -f $file ] || { echo "$file does not exist"; exit 1; }
done

# strip the permissions (whith extended regexes could be more readable)
OWNER=$(ls -l ${reference} | sed -e "s/.\(...\).*/\1/" | sed -e "s/[-]//g" )
GROUP=$(ls -l ${reference} | sed -e "s/....\(...\).*/\1/" | sed -e "s/[-]//g" )
OTHER=$(ls -l ${reference} | sed -e "s/.......\(...\).*/\1/" | sed -e "s/[-]//g" )

chmod u=${OWNER},g=${GROUP},o=${OTHER} ${files}
```

I found that on one of my Solaris 10 machines, `stat` was not found. That might be an issue with my configuration though.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/126755) | -1

Answer (score 0):

I got inspired by @Matteo and @mjlescano. This one-liner works on MacOS without installing any additional dependencies.

```
permcp() { chmod $( stat -f '%A' "$1" ) "${@:2}" } && permcp sourcefile targetfile
```

We have just defined a function and called the function with source and target file parameters. You can use the "`permcp`" function for subsequent invocations if it's required.