# How to clone/copy all file/directory attributes onto different file/directory?

Tags: filesystems, backup, file-copy, xattr

I want to copy the attributes (ownership, group, ACL, extended attributes, etc.) of one directory to another but not the directory contents itself.

This does not work:

```
cp -v --attributes-only A B
cp: omitting directory `A'
```

**Note:** It does not have to be `cp`.

Comment: You did not pass `-r`, so it is ignoring directories. But I guess you want to copy only the attributes, not the contents? I can think of only ugly hacks. Also note that `install` can preserve SELinux contexts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clone ownership and permissions from another file?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20645/clone-ownership-and-permissions-from-another-file)

Comment: @Gilles, thank you for pointing to another topic. It solves part of problem: ownership and mode. What about extended attributes?

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki I'm afraid very few tools support extended attributes. If they're important, use killermist's rsync suggestion.

Comment: Btw. Here are nice examples where one may see xattrs in action: GUI of Dolphin in KDE: https://imgur.com/oguuJNm or URL from where file was downloaded set by browsers: references: https://gist.github.com/gwpl/a00e18bc150f1e3518335d13c5e46ad7 + https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/CommonExtendedAttributes/ + http://vhanda.in/blog/2014/07/tagging-your-files/

Comment: Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20645/clone-ownership-and-permissions-from-another-file and https://askubuntu.com/questions/56792/how-to-copy-only-file-attributes-metadata-without-actual-content-of-the-file/143092

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After quite a bit of trial and error on the commandline, I think I've found the answer.  But it isn't a `cp`-related answer.

`rsync -ptgo -A -X -d --no-recursive --exclude=* first-dir/ second-dir`

This does:

```
-p, --perms                 preserve permissions
-t, --times                 preserve modification times
-o, --owner                 preserve owner (super-user only)
-g, --group                 preserve group
-d, --dirs                  transfer directories without recursing
-A, --acls                  preserve ACLs (implies --perms)
-X, --xattrs                preserve extended attributes
    --no-recursive          disables recursion
```

For reference

```
    --no-OPTION             turn off an implied OPTION (e.g. --no-D)
-r, --recursive             recurse into directories
```

Comment: That last edit is definitely a hit there.  With or without a / on the second-dir, that finally does exactly what is asked, it looks like.

Comment: The trailing slash only makes a difference on the first argument, not the second.  It's explained in the 3rd or 4th paragraph of the `USAGE` section of the `rsync(1)` man page.

Comment: @jw013 After reading the rsync documentation repeatedly, months ago, my conclusion was that the trailing slashes were an implied "into", whether in the first (second, third, etc) or last argument.  But then again, I often end my commands with a / on the last argument to imply/demand an "into" affect.

Comment: My gut feeling to copy all directory attributes and no regular file would be `rsync -a -AX --include='*/' --exclude='*'`. I haven't tested.

Comment: @jw013  Thanks on helping get this answer dialed in.  I tried SO many options on my little sandbox test environment, and kept coming close, but having some part of it not work right.

Comment: it is long , but it works ace!

Answer (score 1):

```
chmod --reference=first-dir second-dir
```

Comment: This won't work recursively, and I believe it will not copy ACLs or extended attributes.

Comment: It's not supposed to be recursive: The OP asked for "not the directory contents itself", and the accepted answer tells rsync `--no-recursive`.  The problem with this answer is that it doesn't do ACLs or XATTRs.

Answer (score 1):

```
rsync -aAX --exclude='*' src_dir/ dst_dir
```

where dst_dir - is a target dir. Or:

```
rsync -dADXgot src_dir dst_dir
```

where dst_dir - is a dir containing target dir, or a non-existing target dir.

From rsync man page:

```
    -a, --archive               archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)
        --exclude=PATTERN       exclude files matching PATTERN

    -d, --dirs                  transfer directories without recursing
    -p, --perms                 preserve permissions
    -A, --acls                  preserve ACLs (implies -p)
    -X, --xattrs                preserve extended attributes
    -o, --owner                 preserve owner (super-user only)
    -g, --group                 preserve group
        --devices               preserve device files (super-user only)
        --specials              preserve special files
    -D                          same as --devices --specials
    -t, --times                 preserve modification times
```

Comment: You forgot hard links.

Comment: These commands just copy permissions/ownership/attributes of a single directory, without content, please read OP question. Hard links are not relevant here.

Comment: Correct. For me hard link or not is an attribute.

Comment: I'm not aware of the filesystems that support hard links to directories. Is there any? Since we are talking about directories, there's no need to specify -H, because the directory can't be a hard link, as far as I concerned. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The ext4 version used by android uses some directory hard links on the `/data` partition (at least in the case of Samsung).

Comment: Thanks for the information. But I tend to disagree with you that `hard link or not` is an attribute, it is more related to the data structure/topology, rather than to attributes of the filesystem object. I think what you suggested is hardly desired in most cases, including OP's question, furthermore rsync does not supported that as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

```
cp -rfp from_dir to_dir
```

- `-r` - recursive
- `-f` - force
- `-p` - preserve attributes: mode, ownership, timestamps

Comment: Also need --attributes-only

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand because it seems to work for others, but the rsync method fails for me on FreeBSD with ZFS.  Nothing happens.  However Jean-François Dockes’s method works.  (see: https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/pxattr/ )  Source directory = A & destination directory = B, from the original question.

```
pxattr -lR A > tmp.EAs
```

(edit the first line of tmp.EAs to change the A directory to B,  s/A/B/)

```
pxattr -S tmp.EAs
```

Comment: So, you’re not just recommending somebody else’s *method;* you’re recommending somebody else’s ***program**,* right? That’s OK, but I just wasted five minutes searching for documentation on a little-known non-standard program. It would be nice if you stated more clearly that you are recommending that people download a little-known non-standard program.

Comment: *shrug*  It’s in the ports tree.  That doesn’t exactly make it non-standard.  It’s not as obscure as `pyxattr` and I tried that too.  This was kind of a hard nut to crack.  Supposedly gnu cp works for this, but I can’t make it go.  Extended Attributes deserve better than this.  Also, pxattr works at least under linux, osx, & bsd.

Answer (score -3):

You need the "-r" for copying a directory.

Comment: I think I misunderstood you, you don't need the contents, just the xattr. If it was for SELinux, you could use chcon referencing the original directory (A).

Comment: `-r` implies copy of all subdirectories and files in them... I do not want to copy whole tree... I want to copy attributes for only one and only one directory - without affecting it's contents.