# copy folder permission to another server

Tags: linux, debian, permissions, tomcat

I have the next problem, i have 2 servers (debian) and each one have install tomcat.

The first server (192.168.0.100) have installed tomcat with their default permissions in every folder (and that’s ok).

But , in my second server (192.168.0.101), someone here put chmod 777 –R to every folder in tomcat, and I don’t know how to restore to the original permissions in every folder.

So, my question is, it’s possible copy the permissions tomcat’s folders from the first server (192.168.0.100) and then set that permissions in tomcat’s folders of the second server (192.168.0.101) ??

Regards

Comment: Someone put `chmod` on purpose, or maybe is it a file system, e.g. FAT, not supporting UNIX permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can either copy the folder with `scp -pr`, preserving permissions and replace it with the old one, or, if the contents, but not the files differ, you can copy it (preserving permissions) and clone permissions:

```
chmod -R --reference REMOTEFOLDER LOCALFOLDER
chown -R --reference REMOTEFOLDER LOCALFOLDER
```

The following answer could also be helpful: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/20646